# Pycharm html indentation

Tags: html, pycharm

I'm not very pleased with the Pycharm auto-indentation when it comes to html-files. Is there a way to configure so that it follows html-standards? Because as it is now tags inside `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>` and a few more are not indented.

Suggestions?

Comment: I hope this is an appropriate question, I figured it was ok since there is a Pycharm category here. Also, I'm running Pycharm Professional Edition (latest version).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may want to look under `Settings -> Project Settings -> Code Style -> HTML`. 
There, in **Other** tab you'll find a setting called **Do not indent children of:**

I think that's what you need.

[image]