# Pycharm and HTML tags

Tags: html, pycharm

Just updated Pycharm, and now it won't recognise any of my HTML tags. Do you also have this issue, or have I messed with some settings? A few days ago I changed a few of the HTML settings, but can't really remember what I did...

[image]

So, all of the yellow marked tags are not recognised by Pycharm anymore? I have no idea what I've done to cause this, unless its an update issue, but I searched online and could not find others with the same problem.

[image]

Comment: Any screenshot or a specific example what's wrong?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Just added a screenshot! So, when I hover the mouse over head (or any other tag) Pycharm starts nagging that it does not recognise tag.

Comment: What do you get on the far right side of the screen?
Where the green square is in this photo:
http://imgur.com/GnESUfL
If it is red, you may be having an issue with Preferences > Code Style >> HTML
But my guess is that your settings in:
 Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts > HTML 
Somehow got messed up. Try changing the Scheme name to another and see if that fixes the highlighting issue.

Comment: Didn't work, still having the same issue...

Comment: It's really strange. I downloaded Pycharm community edition, and there I don't have this problem. Is there a way to reset Pycharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem. Reading through [this bug report](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-522) I tried the following:

> **File | Invalidate caches**

Worked like a (py)charm ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you can refine your post, we'll be able to help you; can you point to a hi-lighted tag with your mouse and read the warning on pycharm status bar. Also you can do this by pointing to the  warning indicators on the right in front of each line. Here are some things you can check:

1. settings/code style/html bring it back to defaults
2. settings/inspection bring it back to defaults
3. settings/file types choose html and check the registered patterns, it may be broken, you should find *.(htm, html, sht, shtm, shtml)
4. you could also un\re-install html tools plugin.

Comment: Tried your suggestions, but I had not changed anything, so they where all set to standard.

Comment: Could you check what you've changed lately, it seems you asked about html code style at May 23 here
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831764/pycharm-html-indentation?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Delete your .idea folder, and then restart pycharm.