# PyCharm - Material Design Lite - Auto Suggest not working

Tags: html, pycharm, autosuggest, material-design-lite

I'm having some issues setting up a new Django project with PyCharm regarding autocompletion of HTML code. I  am using Material Design Lite as a front-end framework, and have the files in a static folder in the project.

I've tried to mark the folder as a Resource,deleted the .idea folder, and

```
file | Invalidate Caches/Restart
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043037/pycharm-and-html-tags) , this made PyCharm go through the indexing phase but it did nothing in the end.

This is really odd to me, since my prior project - running the same version of PyCharm and with seemingly the same settings, the auto suggestions works as inteded.
 [image]

however in my new project I'm setting up, I just cant get it to auto suggest.
[image]

MDL also works despite this when running the server.

Anyone has any idea of what I can do to fix this? I'm thinking I have forgot to do something, but after a day of searching I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

And surprisingly, the day after, it just works without me having to do anything.

Maybe it was the restart of the PC that did it.